# pkg-config errors on windows compiling v8

Tags: c, go, v8, cgo, pkg-config

I am trying to build ry/v8worker2 on windows.  Everything goes fine until the point where I run `go test` which then complains about the pkg-config setup.

This is the pkg-config file which is generated:

```
Name: v8
Description: v8
Version: xxx
Cflags: -IC:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2\v8\include
Libs: out/v8build/obj/v8_monolith.lib
```

And this is the output when `go test` is executed:

```
go build github.com/reaandrew/v8worker2: invalid flag in pkg-config --libs: out/v8build/obj/v8_monolith.lib
FAIL    github.com/reaandrew/v8worker2 [build failed]
```

As I say, the entire compilation went fine and files were created but at the end something is not correct.  The only modifications to the build.py I have made to try and make this work on windows as here:

```
diff --git a/build.py b/build.py
index 2cb5e6a..6f482c8 100755
--- a/build.py
+++ b/build.py
@@ -82,7 +82,7 @@ GCLIENT_SOLUTION = [
 ]

 def main():
-  lib_fn = os.path.join(prebuilt_path, platform_name(), "libv8_monolith.a")
+  lib_fn = os.path.join(root_path.replace("\\","/"),"/out/v8build/obj/v8_monolith.lib")
   if args.rebuild or not os.path.exists(lib_fn):
     print("Rebuilding V8")
     lib_fn = Rebuild()
@@ -99,9 +99,9 @@ def Rebuild():

   EnsureDeps(v8_path)

-  gn_path = os.path.join(depot_tools, "gn")
+  gn_path = os.path.join(depot_tools, "gn.bat")
   assert os.path.exists(gn_path)
-  ninja_path = os.path.join(depot_tools, "ninja")
+  ninja_path = os.path.join(depot_tools, "ninja.exe")
   assert os.path.exists(ninja_path)

   gn_args = GN_ARGS.replace('\n', ' ')
@@ -144,7 +144,8 @@ def EnsureDeps(v8_path):
   env = os.environ.copy()
   # gclient needs to have depot_tools in the PATH.
   env["PATH"] = depot_tools + os.pathsep + env["PATH"]
-  subprocess.check_call(["gclient", "sync", "--spec", spec],                                                           +  gclient_path = os.path.join(depot_tools, "gclient.bat")
+  subprocess.check_call([gclient_path, "sync", "--spec", spec],
                         cwd=root_path,
                         env=env)
```

There is very little documented (that I can find) about how to compile this project on windows.

UPDATE: If I change the pkg-config to:

```
Name: v8
Description: v8
Version: xxx
Cflags: -Iv8/include
Libs: -Lout/v8build/obj/v8_monolith.lib
```

Then the output of `go test` is now:

```
# github.com/reaandrew/v8worker2
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `Recv':
./binding.cc:333: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::HandleScope(v8::Isolate*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9626: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::CreateHandle(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Object*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `Recv':
./binding.cc:338: undefined reference to `v8::Value::IsFunction() const'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9717: undefined reference to `v8::V8::DisposeGlobal(v8::internal::Object**)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9670: undefined reference to `v8::V8::GlobalizeReference(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Object**)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `Recv':
./binding.cc:333: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
./binding.cc:333: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9385: undefined reference to `v8::Locker::Initialize(v8::Isolate*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `Send':
./binding.cc:351: undefined reference to `v8::EscapableHandleScope::EscapableHandleScope(v8::Isolate*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9626: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::CreateHandle(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Object*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `Send':
./binding.cc:356: undefined reference to `v8::Value::IsArrayBuffer() const'
./binding.cc:359: undefined reference to `v8::ArrayBuffer::GetContents()'
./binding.cc:367: undefined reference to `v8::ArrayBuffer::New(v8::Isolate*, void*, unsigned long long, v8::ArrayBufferCreationMode)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:1031: undefined reference to `v8::EscapableHandleScope::Escape(v8::internal::Object**)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:1022: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `Send':
./binding.cc:350: undefined reference to `v8::Locker::~Locker()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:1022: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `Send':
./binding.cc:350: undefined reference to `v8::Locker::~Locker()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `Print':
./binding.cc:313: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::HandleScope(v8::Isolate*)'
./binding.cc:319: undefined reference to `v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Local<v8::Value>)'
./binding.cc:319: undefined reference to `v8::String::Utf8Value::~Utf8Value()'
./binding.cc:313: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
./binding.cc:313: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::HandleScope(v8::Isolate*)'
./binding.cc:319: undefined reference to `v8::String::Utf8Value::~Utf8Value()'
./binding.cc:313: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `ExitOnPromiseRejectCallback(v8::PromiseRejectMessage)':
./binding.cc:65: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()'
./binding.cc:68: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::HandleScope(v8::Isolate*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9626: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::CreateHandle(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Object*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `ExitOnPromiseRejectCallback(v8::PromiseRejectMessage)':
./binding.cc:73: undefined reference to `v8::Exception::CreateMessage(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>)'
./binding.cc:74: undefined reference to `v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::String::NewStringType, int)'
./binding.cc:75: undefined reference to `v8::Context::Global()'
./binding.cc:75: undefined reference to `v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Value>)'
./binding.cc:77: undefined reference to `v8::Value::IsFunction() const'
./binding.cc:80: undefined reference to `v8::Message::GetScriptOrigin() const'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:10289: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:10289: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::GetCurrentContext()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:10289: undefined reference to `v8::Value::ToString(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `ExitOnPromiseRejectCallback(v8::PromiseRejectMessage)':
./binding.cc:82: undefined reference to `v8::Message::GetScriptResourceName() const'
./binding.cc:86: undefined reference to `v8::Context::Global()'
./binding.cc:86: undefined reference to `v8::Function::Call(v8::Local<v8::Value>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)'
./binding.cc:90: undefined reference to `v8::Message::PrintCurrentStackTrace(v8::Isolate*, _iobuf*)'
./binding.cc:68: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `ExceptionString[abi:cxx11](worker_s*, v8::TryCatch*)':
./binding.cc:126: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::HandleScope(v8::Isolate*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9626: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::CreateHandle(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Object*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `ExceptionString[abi:cxx11](worker_s*, v8::TryCatch*)':
./binding.cc:128: undefined reference to `v8::TryCatch::Exception() const'
./binding.cc:128: undefined reference to `v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Local<v8::Value>)'
./binding.cc:131: undefined reference to `v8::TryCatch::Message() const'
./binding.cc:140: undefined reference to `v8::Message::GetScriptOrigin() const'
./binding.cc:140: undefined reference to `v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Local<v8::Value>)'
./binding.cc:142: undefined reference to `v8::Message::GetLineNumber() const'
./binding.cc:151: undefined reference to `v8::Message::GetSourceLine() const'
./binding.cc:151: undefined reference to `v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Local<v8::Value>)'
./binding.cc:158: undefined reference to `v8::Message::GetStartColumn(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const'
./binding.cc:162: undefined reference to `v8::Message::GetEndColumn(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const'
./binding.cc:167: undefined reference to `v8::TryCatch::StackTrace() const'
./binding.cc:167: undefined reference to `v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Local<v8::Value>)'
./binding.cc:167: undefined reference to `v8::String::Utf8Value::~Utf8Value()'
./binding.cc:151: undefined reference to `v8::String::Utf8Value::~Utf8Value()'
./binding.cc:140: undefined reference to `v8::String::Utf8Value::~Utf8Value()'
./binding.cc:128: undefined reference to `v8::String::Utf8Value::~Utf8Value()'
./binding.cc:126: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:8779: undefined reference to `v8::V8::FromJustIsNothing()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:8779: undefined reference to `v8::V8::FromJustIsNothing()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `ExceptionString[abi:cxx11](worker_s*, v8::TryCatch*)':
./binding.cc:128: undefined reference to `v8::String::Utf8Value::~Utf8Value()'
./binding.cc:126: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
./binding.cc:151: undefined reference to `v8::String::Utf8Value::~Utf8Value()'
./binding.cc:140: undefined reference to `v8::String::Utf8Value::~Utf8Value()'
./binding.cc:167: undefined reference to `v8::String::Utf8Value::~Utf8Value()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9385: undefined reference to `v8::Locker::Initialize(v8::Isolate*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:7307: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::Enter()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_load':
./binding.cc:195: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::HandleScope(v8::Isolate*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9626: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::CreateHandle(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Object*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9248: undefined reference to `v8::Context::Enter()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_load':
./binding.cc:200: undefined reference to `v8::TryCatch::TryCatch(v8::Isolate*)'
./binding.cc:202: undefined reference to `v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::String::NewStringType, int)'
./binding.cc:203: undefined reference to `v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::String::NewStringType, int)'
./binding.cc:207: undefined reference to `v8::Script::Compile(v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::ScriptOrigin*)'
./binding.cc:215: undefined reference to `v8::Script::Run()'
./binding.cc:200: undefined reference to `v8::TryCatch::~TryCatch()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9250: undefined reference to `v8::Context::Exit()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_load':
./binding.cc:195: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:7310: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::Exit()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_load':
./binding.cc:193: undefined reference to `v8::Locker::~Locker()'
./binding.cc:210: undefined reference to `v8::TryCatch::HasCaught() const'
./binding.cc:218: undefined reference to `v8::TryCatch::HasCaught() const'
./binding.cc:200: undefined reference to `v8::TryCatch::~TryCatch()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9250: undefined reference to `v8::Context::Exit()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_load':
./binding.cc:195: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:7310: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::Exit()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_load':
./binding.cc:193: undefined reference to `v8::Locker::~Locker()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9385: undefined reference to `v8::Locker::Initialize(v8::Isolate*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:7307: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::Enter()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_send_bytes':
./binding.cc:385: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::HandleScope(v8::Isolate*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9626: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::CreateHandle(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Object*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_send_bytes':
./binding.cc:389: undefined reference to `v8::TryCatch::TryCatch(v8::Isolate*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9626: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::CreateHandle(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Object*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_send_bytes':
./binding.cc:398: undefined reference to `v8::ArrayBuffer::New(v8::Isolate*, void*, unsigned long long, v8::ArrayBufferCreationMode)'
./binding.cc:401: undefined reference to `v8::TryCatch::HasCaught() const'
./binding.cc:403: undefined reference to `v8::Context::Global()'
./binding.cc:403: undefined reference to `v8::Function::Call(v8::Local<v8::Value>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)'
./binding.cc:405: undefined reference to `v8::TryCatch::HasCaught() const'
./binding.cc:389: undefined reference to `v8::TryCatch::~TryCatch()'
./binding.cc:385: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:7310: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::Exit()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_send_bytes':
./binding.cc:383: undefined reference to `v8::Locker::~Locker()'
./binding.cc:389: undefined reference to `v8::TryCatch::~TryCatch()'
./binding.cc:385: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:7310: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::Exit()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_send_bytes':
./binding.cc:383: undefined reference to `v8::Locker::~Locker()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `v8_init':
./binding.cc:414: undefined reference to `v8::platform::CreateDefaultPlatform(int, v8::platform::IdleTaskSupport, v8::platform::InProcessStackDumping, v8::TracingController*)'
./binding.cc:415: undefined reference to `v8::V8::InitializePlatform(v8::Platform*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:7229: undefined reference to `v8::ResourceConstraints::ResourceConstraints()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_new':
./binding.cc:424: undefined reference to `v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator()'
./binding.cc:425: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::New(v8::Isolate::CreateParams const&)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9385: undefined reference to `v8::Locker::Initialize(v8::Isolate*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:7307: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::Enter()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_new':
./binding.cc:428: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::HandleScope(v8::Isolate*)'
./binding.cc:437: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::SetPromiseRejectCallback(void (*)(v8::PromiseRejectMessage))'
./binding.cc:441: undefined reference to `v8::ObjectTemplate::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate>)'
./binding.cc:442: undefined reference to `v8::ObjectTemplate::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate>)'
./binding.cc:444: undefined reference to `v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::String::NewStringType, int)'
./binding.cc:444: undefined reference to `v8::Template::Set(v8::Local<v8::Name>, v8::Local<v8::Data>, v8::PropertyAttribute)'
./binding.cc:446: undefined reference to `v8::FunctionTemplate::New(v8::Isolate*, void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&), v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Signature>, int, v8::ConstructorBehavior, v8::SideEffectType)'
./binding.cc:446: undefined reference to `v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::String::NewStringType, int)'
./binding.cc:446: undefined reference to `v8::Template::Set(v8::Local<v8::Name>, v8::Local<v8::Data>, v8::PropertyAttribute)'
./binding.cc:449: undefined reference to `v8::FunctionTemplate::New(v8::Isolate*, void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&), v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Signature>, int, v8::ConstructorBehavior, v8::SideEffectType)'
./binding.cc:449: undefined reference to `v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::String::NewStringType, int)'
./binding.cc:449: undefined reference to `v8::Template::Set(v8::Local<v8::Name>, v8::Local<v8::Data>, v8::PropertyAttribute)'
./binding.cc:452: undefined reference to `v8::FunctionTemplate::New(v8::Isolate*, void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&), v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Signature>, int, v8::ConstructorBehavior, v8::SideEffectType)'
./binding.cc:452: undefined reference to `v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::String::NewStringType, int)'
./binding.cc:452: undefined reference to `v8::Template::Set(v8::Local<v8::Name>, v8::Local<v8::Data>, v8::PropertyAttribute)'
./binding.cc:455: undefined reference to `v8::Context::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::ExtensionConfiguration*, v8::MaybeLocal<v8::ObjectTemplate>, v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value>, v8::DeserializeInternalFieldsCallback)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9717: undefined reference to `v8::V8::DisposeGlobal(v8::internal::Object**)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9670: undefined reference to `v8::V8::GlobalizeReference(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Object**)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_new':
./binding.cc:457: undefined reference to `v8::Context::Enter()'
./binding.cc:428: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:7310: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::Exit()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_new':
./binding.cc:426: undefined reference to `v8::Locker::~Locker()'
./binding.cc:428: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:7310: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::Exit()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_new':
./binding.cc:426: undefined reference to `v8::Locker::~Locker()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_dispose':
./binding.cc:463: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::Dispose()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9385: undefined reference to `v8::Locker::Initialize(v8::Isolate*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:7307: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::Enter()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_load_module':
./binding.cc:229: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::HandleScope(v8::Isolate*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9626: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::CreateHandle(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Object*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9248: undefined reference to `v8::Context::Enter()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_load_module':
./binding.cc:234: undefined reference to `v8::TryCatch::TryCatch(v8::Isolate*)'
./binding.cc:236: undefined reference to `v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::String::NewStringType, int)'
./binding.cc:237: undefined reference to `v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::String::NewStringType, int)'
./binding.cc:239: undefined reference to `v8::Integer::New(v8::Isolate*, int)'
./binding.cc:240: undefined reference to `v8::Integer::New(v8::Isolate*, int)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:10018: undefined reference to `v8::Value::IsTrue() const'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:10015: undefined reference to `v8::Value::IsTrue() const'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_load_module':
./binding.cc:254: undefined reference to `v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileModule(v8::Isolate*, v8::ScriptCompiler::Source*, v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileOptions, v8::ScriptCompiler::NoCacheReason)'
./binding.cc:269: undefined reference to `v8::String::Utf8Value::~Utf8Value()'
./binding.cc:260: undefined reference to `v8::Module::GetModuleRequestsLength() const'
./binding.cc:261: undefined reference to `v8::Module::GetModuleRequest(int) const'
./binding.cc:262: undefined reference to `v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Local<v8::Value>)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_load_module':
C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:86: undefined reference to `v8::String::Utf8Value::~Utf8Value()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:10061: undefined reference to `v8::ScriptCompiler::CachedData::~CachedData()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_load_module':
./binding.cc:234: undefined reference to `v8::TryCatch::~TryCatch()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9250: undefined reference to `v8::Context::Exit()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_load_module':
./binding.cc:229: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:7310: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::Exit()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_load_module':
./binding.cc:227: undefined reference to `v8::Locker::~Locker()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:10017: undefined reference to `v8::Value::IsTrue() const'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:10016: undefined reference to `v8::Value::IsTrue() const'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9636: undefined reference to `v8::V8::Eternalize(v8::Isolate*, v8::Value*)'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_load_module':
./binding.cc:288: undefined reference to `v8::Module::InstantiateModule(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Module> (*)(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::Local<v8::Module>))'
./binding.cc:292: undefined reference to `v8::TryCatch::HasCaught() const'
./binding.cc:293: undefined reference to `v8::TryCatch::HasCaught() const'
./binding.cc:299: undefined reference to `v8::Module::Evaluate(v8::Local<v8::Context>)'
./binding.cc:302: undefined reference to `v8::TryCatch::HasCaught() const'
./binding.cc:255: undefined reference to `v8::TryCatch::HasCaught() const'
./binding.cc:234: undefined reference to `v8::TryCatch::~TryCatch()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:9250: undefined reference to `v8::Context::Exit()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_load_module':
./binding.cc:229: undefined reference to `v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:7310: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::Exit()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o: In function `worker_load_module':
./binding.cc:227: undefined reference to `v8::Locker::~Locker()'
./binding.cc:262: undefined reference to `v8::String::Utf8Value::~Utf8Value()'
C:\Users\andyrea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build332228766\b055\_x003.o:C:\Users\andyrea\go\src\github.com\reaandrew\v8worker2/v8/include/v8.h:10061: undefined reference to ...
```

Comment: The new error looks like the library wasn't used/found; maybe the relative path is not correct? Just a guess. -- I would have suggested to ask this at https://github.com/ry/v8worker2/issues, but it seems that that project is dead.

Comment: What are the other parameters when `pkg-config --libs` is called?
Also, since you're on Windows you may need to actually call `pkg-config.exe`.
One way that sometimes helps to force this is setting this in the environment:
```
PKG_CONFIG=$(which pkg-config.exe)
```

Comment: try `go build -x -v` so we might try figure out ` invalid flag in pkg-config --libs: out/v8build/obj/v8_monolith.lib`

Comment: The `-L` option informs the linker that libraries can be found in a specified directory, but doesn't tell it to load any specific library. The original script intended to point linker to a specific static library. Adding `-L` here is counterproductive.

Answer (score 1):

For [security reasons](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InvalidFlag), the Go compiler has a whitelist of arguments that can appear in `pkg-config` files, and refuses to use arguments that don't appear on the list. One [whitelist entry](https://golang.org/src/cmd/go/internal/work/security.go#L203) allows pointing the linker to static libraries directly: it covers files with the extension `.a`, but not `.lib`.

You can try putting `[a-zA-Z0-9_/].*\.lib` in the `CGO_LDFLAGS_ALLOW` environment variable to make it pass the check… but I suspect that this would probably not work anyway: `.lib` files are produced by MSVC, and they are in a different format from Unix `ar` (which is what `.a` files are, and probably what the Go compiler expects). The real fix would be get V8 to compile with GCC instead of MSVC and produce a proper `.a` file, but V8 doesn't officially support it on Windows, and getting it to work would apparently require a far more invasive patch.

Comment: Not officially supporting it doesn't mean you can't do it.

Comment: Technically it doesn't, but good luck trying to figure out how to do it with V8's custom build system, patching half the files in the repository, and then trying to fit the resulting patch inside a StackOverflow answer.

Comment: I actually took a look at the build system of V8, and I noticed that in `BUILD.gn` the `is_win` variable conflates 'the target platform is Windows' and 'the compiler is MSVC'; it both includes Windows-specific source files in the build and enables MSVC-specific compiler/linker command-line options. Disentangling the two meanings would be quite nontrivial work.